# Remove a specific inline style value with jQuery.

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, styles

I'd like to remove a specific inline color style from any tag wherever it may show up. The color is styled as style="color: rgb(255, 102, 0);".

I was trying out testing with just the a tag but didn't get very far. Ideas? Not a Jquery person so I need a lot of help :).

```
    $('a[style="color: rgb(255, 102, 0)"]').remove('[style="color: rgb(255, 102, 0)"]');

    $('a[style="color: rgb(255, 102, 0)"]').remove();

    <a style="color: rgb(255, 102, 0)">not orange</a>

    <a style="color: rgb(255, 102, 0);">not orange</a>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use this :

```
$('a[style="color: rgb(255, 102, 0)"]').css('color', '');
```

But this will only work if your style attribute is exactly `"color: rgb(255, 102, 0)"`.

If you want something more reliable, for example accepting other style properties or a color specified in a CSS rule, you'd have to filter :

```
$('a').filter(function(){
   return $(this).css('color')=='rgb(255, 102, 0)'
}).css('color', '');
```

[Demonstration](http://jsbin.com/ekebac/2/edit)

Comment: thank you! Is there a way to filter this out of any tag or do I have to specific each one I want filtered?

Comment: @JennC Yes, use `$('*')` instead of `$('a')`.